# I'm trying the get the data from google analytics inside a service and then use it in the controller. But the promise returned is not getting defined

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics-api, angularjs-service

My Service:

```
app.service('MyFirstService', function() {
    (function(w,d,s,g,js,fjs){
        g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(cb){this.q.push(cb)}};
        js=d.createElement(s);fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics')};
    } (window,document,'script'));

    var promise = gapi.analytics.ready(function() {
        var CLIENT_ID = 'MY_CLIENT_ID_HERE';

        gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
            container: 'auth-button',
            clientid: CLIENT_ID,
        });
        var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
            container: 'view-selector'
        });
        data1 = new gapi.analytics.report.Data({
          query: {
            ids: 'ga:XXXXXX',
            dimensions: '',
            metrics: '',
            segment: '',
            filters: '',
            'start-date': '7daysAgo',
            'end-date': '1daysAgo'
          }
        });
        data1.execute();
        gapi.analytics.auth.on('success', function(response) {
            viewSelector.execute();
        });
        viewSelector.on('change', function(ids) {
            var newIds = {
                query: {
                    ids: ids
                }
            }
        });

        return data1;
    });

    return promise;
});
```

My Controller:

```
app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', 'MyFirstService', function($scope, MyFirstService) {
    MyFirstService.on('success', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }); 
}]);
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at new <anonymous> (http://localhost/main.js:56:17)
```

The error is pointing at the ".on" part of the Controller.
I'm new to Angular and Google Analytics. I think the problem is not in the Angular part but in the Google Analytics API Call part. Any help will be really appreciated. Also, if there is some other better way to do this, please suggest me, if possible, with reference links.

Answer (score 1):

You can understand a service basically as an object. You should wrap the code with the promise into a property (e.g. this.getGapi = function() { var promise (...) return promise; }).
Then in the controller you can call

```
MyFirstService.getGapi().then(function(data) {
console.log(data);
)};
```

for logging out when the promise is kept.

Here is a nice tutorial for services btw:
http://learn-angular.org/#!/lessons/the-service-recipe

Comment: i tried this also, it gives the following error : Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: In Angular there is a service called $q which needs to be injected if you're not using $http (for ajax). When you inject this and then use the resolve and reject keywords it should work. Here is the documentation for that: [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: I'm trying to do something, you could put the code that worked, so I can study?